# ssh - Connection time out after successful connection and exit

Tags: ssh, sshd

I have configured my desktop Ubuntu with sshd and I'm testing that I can log in through a public IP from my Mac. When logging through ssh, the first time works perfectly, but as soon as I close the ssh session and try to start it again it times out, and doesn't work until some minutes have passed. If I try this through the private IP, there's no problem.

Any idea on what's wrong?

EDIT:

Also, if I have an active connection through the public IP and I try port forwarding through ssh on a different terminal session, it also times out. Could it be that the public IP doesn't accept multiple connections at the same time?

Comment: Is there a NAT involved?

Comment: Yes, I'm working with a router, DHCP binding and port forwarding to the binded local ip for the ssh port of the server.

Comment: I don't know for sure, but it may be the NAT. I would try some experiments. I would start by adding a service to another port, and forwarding to it, and see what happens. Also, see if there is rate limiting.

Comment: @ÁlvaroParafita not enough information.

Comment: Tell me what you need, I don't know what else to say. I don't know much about this topic.

What I want is to connect to my home desktop when I'm at work. The intented use is some plain shell sessions through SSH plus port tunneling through ssh to access my Jupyter notebook server, running in the desktop. I've noticed that if I have recently opened a connection (either a shell or a port forwarding) I can't open another for a minute or more, but only when I'm connecting through the public IP, not the private IP. I access the public IP through no-ip, but I don't think that's the problem.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem, couldn't find a solution still...